# Applying a DataTemplateSelector to a single Item

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have created a DataTemplateSelector class. I would like to apply it to a single item, so it chooses a template based on some conditions.

Essentially I'd like to have the equivalent of this in xaml:

```
% if myitem.A
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding myitem.data }"/>
% else if myitem.B
  <Button Content="{Binding myitem.data }"/>

 public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {

        public DataTemplate A {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DataTemplate B {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) {
            var myitem = item as MyItem;
            if (myitem.A)
               return A;
            else if (myitem.B)
               return B;
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }

    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see this article http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector ?

Comment: Yeah, but it assumes I am dealing with a collection of Items. On my View Model, I have just a single Item that I want to select a template for. I have no idea how to apply it to a single item, though. : (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have one item, not a list of items, you can use `ContentPresenter` with a custom `ContentTemplate` to show this item. `ContentTemplate` can use your `TemplateSelector` as you know:

```
       <ContentPresenter x:Name="control">
            <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:MyTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                        <local:MyTemplateSelector.A>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="null" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:MyTemplateSelector.A>
                        <local:MyTemplateSelector.B>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:MyTemplateSelector.B>
                    </local:MyTemplateSelector>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter>
```

This is my `TemplateSelector`:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return A;

        return B;
    }
```

And this line add some content to display:

```
control.Content = "123";
```

Comment: Thanks - I cant get it to work though. I tried this syntax: <ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
    <local:MyTemplateSelector.A>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="test" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyTemplateSelector.A>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>   -- but nothing appears

Comment: Call `yourcontrol.Content = myItem;` to add some data to show

Comment: Ah I see. "Content" attribute of the content presenter as the equialent of for example ItemsSource in a listbox. Thank you!